# Redirect to Apex App from External Website

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway with an apex app.
I pass success_url in payload to redirect back to apex page (Thank You page) after successful transaction.
But they are using POST method to redirect to success_url provided and ORDS error is shown [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ACIs.png).

How can i handle this in Oracle Apex?

Thanks

Tried making a POST rest api in ORDS that also did not work.